# How to resize a kendo ui combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

How can I change the width of kendo ui combobox? I use version: 2012.3.1114
I've tried:

```
#options {
    padding: 30px;
}
#options h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 25px 0 8px 0;
}
.k-combobox{
    width:60px;  }
```

Javascript: `$("#select").kendoComboBox();`

Html:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="null">nada</option>
    <option value="true">ON</option>
    <option value="false">OFF</option>
</select>
```

With a file it works but not in jsfiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Thxtr/46/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $("#select").kendoComboBox();
                $("#select").parent().css('width',"300px");

            });
```

You can also do it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#select").width(400).kendoComboBox();
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an !important css declaration:

```
.k-combobox{
   width: 125px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

other useful way: `.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 200px;"})`
via https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725406/1923256